# Pass a function from a component to another (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an application focused on showing a user's github repositories and information. In a "Section" component I fetch these repositories and display them on the screen.
In the other component "Menu" I wanted it to count these repositories and display them. Should I use props in this case?

**Section Component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Square, Wrapper, Input, Button } from './Section.styled'

export default function Section() {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);

  const searchRepos = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`,
    }).then(res => {
      setLoading(false);
      setRepos(res.data);
      
    })
  }
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchRepos()
  }

  const renderRepo = (repo)=>{
    return(
      <Square>
        {repo.name}
     </Square>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <Input
          placeholder="Usuário"
          value={username}
          onChange={e => { setUsername(e.target.value) }}
        />
        <Button
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          type="submit">
          {loading ? "Buscando..." : "Buscar"}
        </Button>

        
          {repos.map(renderRepo)}
        
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Menu Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { bool } from "prop-types";
import { StyledMenu } from "./Menu.styled";


const Menu = ({ open, ...props }) => {
  const isHidden = open ? true : false;
  const tabIndex = isHidden ? 0 : -1;

  return (
    <>
      <StyledMenu open={open} aria-hidden={!isHidden} {...props}>
        <a href="/" tabIndex={tabIndex}>
          Repositories: 
        </a>
        <a href="/" tabIndex={tabIndex}>
          Followeres:
        </a>
        <a href="/" tabIndex={tabIndex}>
          Following:
        </a>
      </StyledMenu>
    </>
  );
};

Menu.propTypes = {
  open: bool.isRequired,
};

export default Menu;
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

These solutions could be possible in this case when we have received data in one component and want it to appear in another component.

1. Pass the function `searchRepos` as a prop from the `parent` component of both `section` and `menu` component to `section` component, call the function from `section`, this will set data in `parent`, and send data to the `menu` component as props, i.e. called **Lifting up the state**.
2. If the components are far away (deeply nested or have unrelated parent, branch) you can simply make use of [context store](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

3. Last way is to store the data of called API of the component `section` in browser local storage and use it in `menu` component. (NOT RECOMMENDED)